# kerberos_kinit_password failed preauthentication failed

Tags: server, kerberos

i'm using my ubuntu server to join in my windows domain, so i have my samba managed by my windows groups. Everything is working fine but every 3-5 days, i'm getting this error:

```
kerberos_kinit_password failed preauthentication failed
kerberos_kinit_password S0VLFS070@SISTEMA.COM.BR failed: Preauthentication failed
Join to domain is not valid: Logon  failure
```

So, i have to run this commands:

```
kinit administrador@SISTEMA.COM.BR
net ads join -U administrador
```

After that, everything backs to normal.

This problem occurs when i'm running ubuntu server 14 or ubuntu server 16.
I have an old ubuntu server 12 who dont have this problem. The problem is i can't install a new ubuntu server 12 because the packs isn't available anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: After a couple of days the kerberos credentials time out (you can inspect that with `klist`)
For some reason you are repeatedly kicked out of the domain and automatically join it. This fails once your credentials time out. 
Have a look at the samba / winbind / active domain logs if you can find out what is going wrong with your domain membership